# Site not reachable from my network only

Tags: amazon-web-services, wordpress

I have created an ec2 instance on aws and hosted my wordpress website

```
http://www.techsteroid.com
```

Every device not on my network is able to reach the site properly, but those on mine are not. Devices on neighbour's network(of the same company) are also not able to reach. I am not able to login to wp-admin and start real development on blog. Kindly help me to connect to my website. Here is how the security group rules look like.
[image]

If any other information is needed, pls tell me. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I am able to reach [techsteroid](http://www.techsteroid.com) from my end. Based on your ACLs (access lists) created on AWS, all IP addresses should be able to view your website via the default port, 80.

You may want to troubleshoot some DNS issues on your internal end. Here are a few things you should try to see where the issue may lie:

1. On your windows/mac/*nix system, run `nslookup www.techsteroid.com`

   - This should return an address of `52.8.152.90`. If it does not, you have a DNS resolution issue.
2. To further prove that it may be a DNS issue, see if you can `telnet www.techsteroid.com 80`. If you can connect via telnet port 80, see if you can get the main page of your website by typing `GET /` into your telnet prompt.
3. On AWS, enable `Type: ICMP, Protocol: TCP, Source: 0.0.0.0/0`. Afterwards, see if you can `ping www.techsteroid.com`.

   - This should definitely return some kind of response. If it does not, you may have some ACL on **your end** (not AWS) blocking you.

The hail mary solution to see if it is a DNS issue, modify your **hosts file** with administrator/sudo privileges and manually insert `52.8.152.90 www.techsteroid.com`, save the file, and then try to access [techsteroid](http://www.techsteroid.com). If this does not work, you may want to double check your own **internal firewall rules** and see if there are any ACLs preventing you from accessing the webpage.

Comment: How can I modify hosts file?

Comment: **Windows system**: Open notepad **with administrator privileges**, file > open > `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` > insert `52.8.152.90 www.techsteroid.com` > save. **Mac/Linux**: Open `/etc/hosts` with sudo privileges > insert `52.8.152.90 www.techsteroid.com` > save

Comment: Thanks , I m now able to open the website. when I ran the command nslookup, it says can't find. server lookup failed.

Comment: If you are on a **windows system**, try to run `ipconfig /flushdns` and then try `nslookup www.techsteroid.com`.

Comment: Still seeing same error.

Comment: Also I am no more able to connect to the site via FileZilla, which was working fine until now. Also there is all ICMP rule, but I can't select TCP in that

Comment: It appears that the question has now turned away from "how do I access my website" to now "I am having trouble understanding DNS, TCP, FTP, allow access to my custom EC2 resources". That's a lot to ask of anyone.

Comment: @MikeFiedler yes maybe, but FileZilla was working until now. It just stopped after editing the hosts file. It is important to connect through FileZilla as I need to upload a file